Setting the Size of a Canvas width and height issue
I'm trying to set the size of a canvas for a chart made with Chart.js. It isn't resizing.


let ctx= document.createElement("canvas")
ctx.width = 200
ctx.height = 100
document.body.appendChild(ctx)

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["a", "b"],
        datasets: [{data: [1,2]},{data: [1,2]}],
    }
 })
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>




By default, chart js has its charts set as responsive which makes them adjust to their container dimensions. So your canvas starts at 200 but it immediately re-adjusts taking the full width of the container.
See: here
Solution:
Just add a param that disables it on initialization, like this:
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    // ADDTION HERE
    options: {
      responsive: false,
    },
    data: {
        labels: ["a", "b"],
        datasets: [{data: [1,2]},{data: [1,2]}],
    }
 })

Now this will make it to maintain its canvas dimensions.
See the working example here on Stackblitz
Hope that helps : )
